# Mootools - how to chain multiple jsonp requests

Tags: javascript, api, mootools, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm working with the youtube api to retrieve the info of a list of videos. So i have to use the Request.JSONP class.

My problem is that I have to make multiple calls to the youtube API and I can't make it "chain". The doc says that all I need is to add the option `link:'chain'` and do it in sync mode using `async:false` (witch works fine on a simple Request object).

This is what i've tried:

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    listVideos: [],
    videosInfo: [],
    initialize : function(listVideos){
        this.listVideos = listVideos;
        this.getVideosInfo();
    },
    getVideosInfo : function(){
        var request = new Request.JSONP({
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            link : 'chain',
            async : false,
            onComplete: function(data){
                this.videosInfo.push(data.entry);
                console.log(this.videosInfo);
            }.bind(this)
        });

        this.listVideos.each(function(videoId){
            request.options.url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + videoId + '?v=2&alt=json-in-script&format=5';
            request.send();
        });
        console.log("this should be displayed AFTER the requests, not BEFORE u_u");
        console.log(this.videosInfo);
    }
});


var test = new MyClass(['AJso1SJT7Js','hlO5UBxuJlY'])
```

here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/RNJAK/) so you can play with it n_n

Basically what I want is to process the `videosInfo` array after all the request are completed.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance

**PS:**
I found a "dirty solution" to my problem, http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/gLF5h/1/  but i don't feel comfortable with it at all, if one of the request fails.. it will all fail

Comment: have a look at Request.Queue from more - i don't expect it to work for Request.JSONP but you may be able to apply the principle there to do your own queueing.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff it works with JSONP :) http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/vyLq6/3/ However when using Request.Queue you have to be careful because you loose the class context (this) on each request, so i had to use the "onComplete" event on the Request.Queue to add each response to the this.videosInfo attribute :) Thanks!, if you put your comment as a response I'd be glad to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't disable `async`, lest you freeze the UI thread for the duration of he HTTP request and response.

The [Request.JSONP](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.JSONP) API supports a `onComplete` callback.

You can chain the requests without losing the async nature of AJAX by having each `onComplete` call the subsequent request.

Comment: yeap i thought of that too... I ended up using the Request.Queue to manage the requests, so i wouldn't have to worry if one of the request fails or takes too much time :)